# Azure Powershell - find the NIC based on the private IP

Tags: azure, powershell, powershell-7.2

I am very new to Azure and Powershell. I need to find my Network Interface based on the private IP address. I found "Get-AzNetworkInterface" cmdlet and I want it to return only the entry that contains the IP. I noticed that the IP only exists in "IpConfigurationsText" but not in the "IpConfigurations" which only contains an object name. I don't know if this is normal. The returned "IpConfigurationText" is a list (based on my limited python experience) with dictionary key-value pairs like this

```
[
 {
   "Name": "xxxx",
   "Id": "xxxx",
   "PrivateIpAddress": "10.1.2.3",
   ...
 }
]
```

I guess I want to filter based on its content. I have tried the following but none succeeded...

```
Get-AzNetworkInterface | Where-Object { $_.IpConfigurationsText["PrivateIpAddress"] -contains "10.1.2.3" }
Get-AzNetworkInterface | Where-Object { $_.IpConfigurationsText[0]["PrivateIpAddress"] -eq "10.1.2.3" }
```

I also tried to display only the IP in the output instead of the dictionary key-value pair without success too

```
Get-AzNetworkInterface | select Name,IpConfigurationsText["PrivateIpAddress"]
```

Let me know what I missed.

By the way, I also found out I can use the "Out-GridView" to see and filter the result but it doesn't show me the entire output when it is big. It got truncated. I also can't seem to do copy/paste on it... Any advice on that too?

Thanks!
Difan

Comment: According to the examples in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/get-aznetworkinterface?view=azps-7.1.0#examples), the `IpConfigurations` property should also contain the `PrivateIpAddress`..  
This property is JSON, so did you try `ConvertFrom-Json` on that?

Otherwise, you could try the `IpConfigurationsText` (which is also Json) like `Get-AzNetworkInterface | Select-Object IpConfigurationsText | Where-Object { ($_ | ConvertFrom-Json)["PrivateIpAddress"] -eq "10.1.2.3" }`

Comment: @Theo Thanks for your valuable input! I think I have some fundamental misunderstanding about the shell and the cmdlet. While trying your suggestions, I noticed that if I use `out-gripview` option, my `IpConfigurations` field is just `{ipconfig1}` and the `IpConfigurationsText` will have all details. If I don't use `out-gripview`, in the shell console I see everything printed in `IpConfigurations` and I don't see the `IpConfigurationsText` field. Even more strange, if I use `Select-Object IpConfigurations` option, I will again only see `{ipconfig1}` for the value...

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$IP = (Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $VMName -ResourceGroupName $RGName).IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress
```

if you don`t have the module you need to install i:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Install-Module AzureRm
```

[more info](https://azurelessons.com/the-term-get-azurermvm-is-not-recognized/)

Comment: Thanks @Tal Folkman. I should have mentioned that I don't know my VMName. I am from the networking team and all I have is a private IP and I need to find out which VM it is. Also I can't run this command... I got this error `Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface: The term 'Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.`. I should have the latest power shell and azure cmdlets installed...

Comment: look at the edit @DifanZhao

Answer (score 0):

```
$IP = [IP you want to search)
$VMID = (Get-AzNetworkInterface | where {$_.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress -eq $IP}).VirtualMachine.Id
If (!$VMID) {
Write-Host "$IP Not Found"
}ELSE {
$VMName = $VMID.Substring($VMID.LastIndexOf('virtualMachines/')+16)
}
```

$VMName will hold the plain text name of the VM with that private IP.